# how to close all tabs except current with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to make the extension for google chrome to close all tabs except current. I have found examples to close all tabs, for instance:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
    }
});
```

But I don't know how to add the condition for current tab in order to current tab stay opened. Could you give me example of code that closes all tabs except the current one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I came up with a way to do this.
The code below is still a bit messy but works fine.

```js
 chrome.tabs.query({active:true,windowType:"normal", currentWindow: true},function(d){document.getElementById("Current-tab-id").innerHTML = d[0].id;})

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
           
console.log(tab.id);
var CurrentTabId = document.getElementById('Current-tab-id').innerHTML;
console.log(CurrentTabId);
if(CurrentTabId == tab.id) {

} else {
  chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function callback(){})
}
    });
});
```

What you do is loop through each tab and get i'ts id, then get the current tab id and check if the current tab id matches the tab id from the loop.
If they match, do nothing and if they don't match, remove the tab.
Hope this helps.

Comment: why not simply query by "active: false?